# Solving equation for specific variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to solve this formula for x. Can anybody help please?

$$\ p = r + \frac{(s-r)}{[1+(a|x|)^n]^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtract r from both sides, reciprocate both sides, mutiply both sides by $s-r$, rase both sides to the $\frac{1}{1-1/n}$ power, subtract $1$ from both sides, divide both sides by $a^n$, raise both sides to the $\frac{1}{n}$ power and you get $|x|$, which is all you can get (there isn't enough information to determine the sign or in the complex case, phase, of $x$).